# SSRS - data source issue

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm looking at some issues with a migration of a huge amount of rdl's, the guy that has done this has shifted them and they work, so that's good.

But... if I download one of them the datasource is still the original datasource not the one he changed it to using the web interface.

If I download it, its the old db connection. If I view via the web interface it shows the correct datasource, and then... if I right click and edit through report builder (via the web interface) it shows the updated datasource.

If I save it updates it as I would expect.

Am I missing something here?

Personally, I would never edit a report via the web thing, I would always edit the file and redeploy.

Is there some way I can republish them all without opening each one and saving (I'm 85 into 450 of them and am bored shitless!)

Answer (score 0):

This is both a question and a possible answer. Have you restarted your instance of SSRS? If the data source is shared, and has been modified, you shouldn't have to open the reports in the builder for them to reflect the modification, so alternatively it sounds like the connections are cached and a restart should clear that up.

Comment: the server has been restarted numerous times, the datasource has been changed from an embedded one to a shared for all of them, but all of this has been via the web interface, there have been some caching issues but those I've resolved. My issue is, whilst the reports work correctkly - looking at the new db, if you download the report via the web interface you get the old connection details, this was the first time I downloaded them so I would expect them to be the same as the server details.